# bibtex-ruby: Replace multiple strings in author field

Tags: ruby, bibtex

I would like to define author names through @string entries in a bibtex file and replace them upon parsing the file.

```
@string { author1 = "J. Doe" }
@string { author2 = "J. Smith" }
```

So far so good. The tricky part comes, when entering e.g. an article entry that should use these abbreviations. I tried several combinations like

```
author = {author1 and author2}
author = "author1 and author2"
```

but the only version that seemed to work was the following, where I had to concatenate three strings:

```
author = author1 # " and " # author2
```

which a) looks awkward and b) makes things rather more complicated than easier, particularly for longer author lists. Does anybody know of a better way how to effectively use strings for multiple author replacement in bibtex files?

Would this be a valid feature request/bug report at bibtex-ruby or am I missing some good reason not to use that feature in that case?

Comment: `@string { author1 = "J. Doe" }` - is a block sent to `@string` variable. Is that for sure what you mean it to be?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko While it looks like this could be Ruby, it's not. It's a Bibtex declaration. Check the tag. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and my current best solution is as follows. 
Define another `@string` assigning `" and "` to a single letter, e.g. "y" as in the Spanish for "and"; then use `#y#` between author strings. It is slightly less repetitive and ugly

```
% define authors as strings
@string{alice = "A. Alice"}
@string{bob = "B.~B. Bob"}
@string{cal = "C. Callum"}

% define repetitive " and " string. I've used "y" as in the Spanish for "and"
@string{y = " and "}

@misc {citationkey,
    author = alice #y# bob #y# cal,
    title = "A title",
    }
```

[image: Voila]